# Add Class to the first 5 elements within a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I swear I've done this before, but I'm trying to count the first 5 items within a div and then add a class to them and then add a class to the rest.

I have this:

```
var counter = 0;
$('.images img').each(function(i) {
   if (i == 0) {
       counter = 0;
   } else {
       counter++;
   }
   if (counter < 5) {
       $(this).addClass('this');
   } else {
     $(this).addClass('other');
   }
});
```

which works, but I feel that it could be cleaned up a bit. Any suggestions to make this a bit leaner?

Comment: Why do you need jQuery? Why not just do it with CSS selectors?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve expected result , use below option

1. Loop div with .each
2. Check index and addClass
3. Exit from loop after 5th element using return false

```js
$('div').each(function(index) {
  if(index < 5){
    $(this).addClass('mark')
}else {
return false;
  }
})
```

```css
.mark{
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14</div>
<div>15</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>1</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution is to not use JavaScript, but just use a CSS Selector. nth child will let you target a range of items.

```css
li {
  background-color: yellow;
}

li:nth-child(-n+5) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
</ul>
```

---

If you want to use jQuery, you can simplify it with `.slice(start, end)`

```js
var lis = $('li');
lis.slice(0,5).addClass('on');
lis.slice(5).addClass('off');
```

```css
.off {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.on {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
</ul>
```

---

or you can use the function option in `.addClass(function)`

```js
$('li').addClass( function (index) {
 return index < 5 ? 'on' : 'off';
})
```

```css
.off {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.on {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can use [`:lt()`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) (where the index is zero-based)

```
$('.images img:lt(5)').addClass('this')
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can go with pure css by using .images img:nth-child(-n+5) { stuff}

```css
.test {
  color: green;
  background: yellow;
}

.img span:nth-child(-n+3) {
  color: red !important;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <span class="test">TEST</span>
  <span class="test">TEST</span>
  <span class="test">TEST</span>
  <span class="test">TEST</span>
  <span class="test">TEST</span>
</div>
```